# Ошибка в TCP сервере

Tags: javascript, node.js

Писал tcp сервер через сокет `new net.Socket`

```js
var net = require('net');
var clientSocket = new net.Socket;

clientSocket.setEncoding('utf8');

clientSocket.connect({
  port: 8080,
  host: 'localhost'
}, function() {
  console.log('connected to server');
  clientSocket.write('Hello \n');
});

clientSocket.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

clientSocket.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Выводит ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем ошибка ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код, который Вы привели - это код клиента, который пытается подключиться на localhost. Но вот только похоже, там его никто не ждет. Поэтому, и будет наблюдаться указанная выше ошибка. Решение следующее - проверить, что сервер действительно существует и он запущен на порту 8080, также, что он слушает этот порт и фаервол не забанил его.